# Many to many Relationship with in an entity

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate entity called provider as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Provider {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;    


    @Column
    private String type;    

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

It contains different types of providers based on type,

- For student provider - type is st
- For course provider - type is cp

Here i need to make many-to-many relationship between student provider and course provider.For that i had created a new entity as follows,

```
public class StudentToCourseProvider {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Provider studentProvider;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private List<Provider> courseProvider;

    public Provider getStudentProvider() {
        return studentProvider;
    }

    public void setClinicalProvider(Provider studentProvider) {
        this.studentProvider = studentProvider;
    }

    public Provider getCourseProvider() {
        return courseProvider;
    }

    public void setCourseProvider(Provider courseProvider) {
        this.courseProvider = courseProvider;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

i need to create **StudentToCourseProvider** entity without id(primary key).How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use inheritence:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritence(strategy = InheritenceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Provider { ... }

@Entity
@Discriminator("st")
public class StudentProvider extends Provider {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<CourseProvider> courseProviders = ...;
}

@Entity
@Discriminator("cp")
public class CourseProvider extends Provider {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courseProviders")
    private List<StudentProvider> studentProviders = ...;
}
```

In this case you remove `type` field from `Provider` class and turn it into discriminator. This works if you have predefined set of possible types.

Alternatively, you can create a single many-to-many relationship in `Provider` and enforce your constraints in code. This would work if you have indeterminate set of possible types. Note that you should take care of directinality of relationship in this case.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment,can you please explain more clear,i cant understand how to create entity using inheritance